# In magento 2 admin product-catalog page how to add a additional option in back orders select field under advance Inventory

Tags: magento2, catalog-product

In magento 2 admin product-catalog page how to add a additional option in  back orders select field under advance Inventory

[image: e]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluginize **toOptionArray** method of following class, add your custom option.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/Source/Backorders.php

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Backorders">
        <plugin name="sr_add_option_to_backorder"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Backorders" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/CatalogInventory/Model/Source/Backorders.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Model\Source;


class Backorders
{
    public function afterToOptionArray(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Backorders $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        $result = array_merge($result, [
            ['value' => '10', 'label' => __('Custom')]
        ]);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: its work.  i need a another favor from you. can u please explain  about how to add extra field in under advance inventory.

Comment: Simply using ui component. Check CatalogInventory module.

Comment: Hello @SohelRana. Can you please help me here ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/273762/17154

Answer (score 1):

Download this module with Plugin, edit it like you want.

http://www.filedropper.com/webmeridianbackorderextra

after install please run :

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento c:c
```