# Magento 2 form xml visibility fieldset conditional

Tags: module, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2, ui-form

I have added a new fieldset tab on the Cart Price Rule.

But I would like to hide on a conditional, I've tried:

```
...<fieldset name="custom_rule" sortOrder="100">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>false</opened>
            <label translate="true">Custom Rule</label>
        </settings>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">sales_rule_form.sales_rule_form.hide</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
       .....
```

**DataProviderPlugin:**

```
public function public function afterGetData(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider $subject, $result)
{
    if(is_array($result)){
        foreach ($result as $key=>$item) {
            $item['hide'] = 1;
        }
    }
    //print_r($item);die;
    return $result;
}
```

I can see in print it has hide key set as 1.

[image]

I get Error:

> There has been an error processing your request Boolean value is
>   expected, supported values: array (   0 => true,   1 => 1,   2 =>
>   'true',   3 => '1',   4 => false,   5 => 0,   6 => 'false',   7 =>
>   '0', ) Error log record number: 761245652727

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229505/is-it-possible-to-add-condition-in-admingrid-form-using-ui-component-solved/229523#229523

Comment: @ChiragPatel  visible is what I am looking for and for FieldSet bot a field. I've tried it doesn't seem to work for fieldset! does it work for you in for a fieldset?