# Hide a Ui Component Field based on condition on product edit

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, products, data-provider

I have created custom field in Magento 2.4.1 product edit page,

product_form.xml

```
<field name="type" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Ceymox\DigitalCard\Model\DigitalCard\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Digital Card Type</label>
                <dataScope>type</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <file name="csv_uploader" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">CSV File</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item> 
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Allowed file type: csv.</item>
                    <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="digitalcard/index/generate"/>
                    </item> 
                </item>
            </argument>
        </file>
        
        <insertListing name="digitalcard_listing" >
            <settings>
                <dataLinks>
                    <exports>false</exports>
                    <imports>true</imports>
                </dataLinks>
                <autoRender>true</autoRender>
                <selectionsProvider>digitalcard_listing.digitalcard_listing.columns.ids</selectionsProvider>
                <dataScope>digitalcard_listing</dataScope>
                <ns>digitalcard_listing</ns>
            </settings>
        </insertListing>
     </fieldset>
```

Now I need to hide this field based on condition(based on product type).How can i do this? can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

**Check this link for reference :-**

[How to Create Dependent Fields in Forms using Ui components- Magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-dependent-fields-in-forms-using-ui-components-magento2/)

Comment: This toggles visibility based on the value of another form element. The question is about using the product type to determine visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Magento combines the data from your product_form.xml file with any custom data in you [modifier class](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/customize-modifier-class.html). What the Magento docs are not very clear about is the merging order. Magento uses whatever your `modifyMeta()` method returns to **override** the config from product_form.xml. This means that you can do the following:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface $locator
)
{
    $this->locator = $locator;
}

public function modifyMeta(array $meta): array
{
    $product = $this->locator->getProduct();

    if ($product->getTypeId() != "configurable")
    {
        $meta['your-group-id']['children']['your_field_id']['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            "componentType" => "fieldset",
            "collapsible" => false,
            "sortOrder" => 1,
            'opened' => false,
            'canShow' => false,
            'visible' => false
        ];
    }

    return $meta;
}
```