# Magento 2: How can i check if field has data while Viewing the form(Ui component) data in backend

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, adminform

I created form using ui-component. after filling the data i display the data into backend.
I want to display those field who has data in View action.

EX. i want to remove company label if it's blank/null.
Please Help.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to do this on the frontend? Something along the lines of `if="company.value.length"`

Comment: i can, but how will it affect in backend?

Comment: Changing the frontend HTML will have no impact on the backend. If you'd like to achieve this in the backend then I'm not sure.

Comment: @Fenashah A data provider is used the set the value to the field. if you want to hide or show a field then you have to extend the component using JS.