# How to use a modifier to disable an UI Component field?

Tags: magento2, php, admin, grid, uicomponent

Hi i'm new at magento 2 and i want to disable an UI component field while edit a product, and shows the field while creating new product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, but wasn't using a modifier. I followed this tutorial: [Disabling a UI component field upon condition in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173081/disabling-a-ui-component-field-upon-condition-in-magento-2/177395#177395)